# Autocontenido en los archivos .properties con objetos con Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, archivo-de-propiedades

estoy desarrollando una aplicación con Springboot y tengo 2 ficheros de configuración, el .properties y el .yml.

En el .yml tengo:

```
available-channels-list:
 profile: 
  -
    rolCatalogue: "perfil_1"
    rolWcm: "_perfil_1"
  -
    rolCatalogue: "perfil_2"
    rolWcm: "_perfil_2"
```

Como se puede ver, es un array formado por guiones, cuyo objeto tiene 2 propiedades.

Ahora necesito obtener estos parámetros del .properties:

Entonces he cambiado el desarrollo a:

.properties

```
env.roles.rolCatalogue[0]: perfil_1
env.roles.rol.rolWcm[0]: _perfil_1
env.roles.rolCatalogue[1]: perfil_2
env.roles.rol.rolWcm[1]: _perfil_2
```

.yml:

```
roles: ${env.roles}
```

Y para recuperar el contenido:

```
List<Profile> as = (List<Profile>) env.getProperty("roles",Profile.class);


@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Profile {
    private String rolCatalogue;
    private String rolWcm;
}
```

El error es:

> "shortMessage": "Could not resolve placeholder 'env.roles' in value
>   \"${env.roles}\"", "detailedMessage": "Could not resolve placeholder
>   'env.roles' in value \"${env.roles}\""

Otra opción que he intentado es:

En el yml:

```
available-channels-list:
 profile: 
  -
    rolCatalogue: ${env.rol.rolCatalogue}
    rolWcm:  ${env.rol.rolWcm}
```

Y en el properties:

```
env.roles.rolCatalogue[0]: perfil_1
env.roles.rol.rolWcm[0]: _perfil_1
env.roles.rolCatalogue[1]: perfil_2
env.roles.rol.rolWcm[1]: _perfil_2
```

Para recogerlo:

```
// Anotacion
@Autowired
private ListRoles profiles;

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "available-channels-list")
@Configuration
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ListRoles {
  List<Profile> profile;
}
```

Aquí la clave es: available-channels-list

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Profile {
    private String rolCatalogue;
    private String rolWcm;
}
```

Esto funciona si tengo el array directamente en el yml, pero al hacerlo para el .properties no soy capaz, sólo me trae los textos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo puedo poner un array de clave-valor en el .properties para leerlo en el .yml? o ¿en la aplicación? Es decir, sino puedo volcarlo del .properties al .yml pues lo leo directamente del .properties,pero eso fue lo 1º que intenté y tampoco funcionó...

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ocupar un  map para determinar el key y el value, no es necesario usar 2 archivos de propiedades, solo en el properties

```
 valuesMap={perfil1: env.rol.rolCatalogue[0], perfil2: env.rol.rolCatalogue[1]}
```

Y usarlo de la siguiente manera

```
@Value("#{${valuesMap}}")
private Map<String, Integer> valuesMap;
```

Para más información puedes leer el post.

```
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation
```

Comment: Gracias Omar, justamente lo acabo de resolver, te voto +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Lo he podido resolver de la siguiente manera:

En el .properties:

```
env.rol.rolCatalogue[0]: perfil_1
env.rol.rolWcm[0]: _perfil_1
env.rol.rolCatalogue[1]: perfil_2
env.rol.rolWcm[1]: _perfil_2
```

En el .yml he borrado las referencias para que lo lea directamente del .properties

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="env.rol")
@Configuration
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Profile {
    private String[] rolCatalogue;
    private String[] rolWcm;
}
```

De esta clase me faltaban los []

```
// Anotacion
@Autowired
private Profile profiles;
```

Como no sé como volcarlo en el yml, lo he tenido que leer directamente del .properties.